# Django: bigger querysets & small no. of database hits or vice versa

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am developing a website on django & MySQL which is similar to linkedin in terms of complexity and functionality and am expecting steep growth for a few months.

I have one question. While designing the models and the views, I have two options. Either go for smaller number of database hits and handle bigger querysets(by making more complex queries & more joins) or handle smaller querysets thereby increasing the number of database hits. For example, when I use prefetch_related() & select_related(), the no. of database hits is reduced significantly, but the size of the querysets and the no of joins performed on the tables increase. This is just one example.

So considering the conditions under production, what should i prefer out of the above two. A little explanation would be better.

Comment: no, not at present. because i read somewhere that its not necessary until the number of of hits on the website increase too much.

Comment: I guess, that you are still using the django's default caching. Of course, it is not necessary for small apps. But it is recommended. The basic logic is that you're creating an additional layer between logics and database. So you don't have to hit the db for all of the data.

Comment: And your question heavily dependes on a lot of factors. What kind of data do you store? What kind of queries are you performing? What are the most popular ones? Do you need all the data from them? How are you going to scale your application? There is no "always-do-so" answer.

Comment: So, if I am using memcached, then while loading the newsfeed, when first user hits the database, i can store the results in cache and when the next users load the newsfeed, in normal conditions, the databse won't be hit? But then its again almost the same question, the cache will utilize RAM, without cache, more database hits. Which one should i select.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But we are back to the number of factors. Do you have a significant amount of RAM? If yes - everything's good. If not - well, I guess you get the point.

Comment: To speak the truth, the server I am going to start with has only 1 GB of RAM, and that is one of my biggest concern while taking this kind of decision. Ok one question, with 1 GB RAM, is it good to go for memcached or better use the default caching of django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly better to go for smaller number of database hits because that may as well be your bottleneck when performance is critical.

Having more hits is almost like hitting the hard disk for a file every time you want to read a line. Of course the final answer depends on the frequency of your usage and the actual gains you derive by putting the queries together. For example, does it mean that you have to cache the data longer? How will it affect your app if it has to do the same for lots of users?

One way to start off is to try and reduce the number of query sets within the same function - if one function is doing 100 separate queries then you can do better by putting them together, if possible.

Comment: thats a good explanation, but presently, I am doing 50 joins to load the newsfeed out of which many are getting repeated. With more number of database hits, i can reduce it to 15-20 joins. So what should i do. Use a caching framework or rely on django default caching.

Comment: One of the biggest mistakes in softwares is premature optimisation. Stay with django default caching for now, unless you find a reason to move away from it. With 1gb ram you will quickly come to know of shortfalls, if any.